# How i can get the price in input field instead of span?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Value showing in span but I need to get value in the input field.

There will also be Product 3, 4, and so on.

The input field name, price, id, class is being populated dynamically from a database so they are the same for different Items.

If one product exists then it's fine however with multiple products and their options the price for the first ID only changes. As an example, if I change the select from Product 2 then the price of Product 1 changes only. How can I get it to stick to its own Product and change the price for that one only?

```js
$(".readers").change(function() {
  var productParent = $(this).parent().parent();
  var newPrice = parseFloat(productParent.find('.price').attr('data-price'));
  productParent.find(".readers option:selected").each(function() {
    newPrice += +$(this).attr('data-price')
  });
  productParent.find(".price").html("&pound;" + newPrice.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span data-name="product_name">Addon Product</span></p>
<p data-name="product_desc"> Addon product descriptions</p>
<hr class="line">
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Size: </label>
    <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
      <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
      <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
      <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <span class="price pull-left" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">&pound;5.99</span>
  <hr/>
</div>
<div>
  <p><span data-name="product_name">2nd Product</span></p>
  <p data-name="product_desc">2nd Addon product description</p>
  <hr class="line">
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Size: </label>
      <select class="product-variants readers form-control input-sm" id="readers" name="product_size">
        <option data-price="0" value="Small">Small</option>
        <option data-price="40" value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option data-price="60" value="Large">Large</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <span class="price pull-left" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">&pound;5.99</span>
    <hr/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to understand your question, as your example seems to work fine by me. What are you expecting to happen vs what are you observing?

Comment: When I change the size then the price showing in span but I want the price in the input field

Comment: oh so you want something like -> when you click the dropdown you see;
small - 5.99
Medium - 45.99
Large - 65.99

Comment: no span i want in input box

Comment: what's confusing is that your example does not have any `input`.. to change the value of an input with jquery use $('input').val(yourValue)

Comment: <span class="price pull-left" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99">&pound;5.99</span>
I want to change this to  <input class="price pull-left" itemprop="price" id="price" data-price="5.99"/>